# How to get additional info using Django annotate?

Tags: django, django-models, group-by

Here is an example:

I have table Book (publish_time, book_name, authors), Author (author_name, books), and they are ManyToMany.

Now I try to get the latest published book for each author.

Like:

**author** | **latest_publish_time** | **book_name**

1   |   2015-01-01    |    The book

I can get the latest_publish_time with author easily:

```
Author.objects.values('name').annotate(latest_publish_time=Max('books__publish_time'))
```

But I don't know how to get the book name at the same time. Please help.

Comment: I used raw sql in django to solve that question (nested sql). I don't know whether it's possible to do that in "pure" django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about querying for it and then filtering it in python? Something like this may do what you are looking for.

```
all_books = Author.objects.values('id', 'name', 'books__name', 'books__publish_time').order_by('-books__publish_time')

latest_books = {}
for row in all_books:
    author_id = row[0]
    if author_id in latest_books:
        continue
    latest_books[author_id] = row
```

Comment: I used raw sql to solve that question finally. But this looks like working. Will try it. Thanks.